# Can't center site in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, centering

This is an embarrassingly basic problem, but I've been wracking my brains trying to find the solution and finally the frustration got too much for me...

All I'm trying to do is center a website in IE7. It works fine in Firefox, Safari, IE8, and Chrome. Just not IE7:

```
#container
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1035px;
}
```

I just can't see how this can go wrong. I've tried strict and transitional doctypes, I've also put the body in a text-align:center (makes no difference).

Any advice on this matter would be gratefully received.

Ok, here's (some of the) surrounding code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen" />

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="content-container">
            <div id="content">

                /* content */               

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS (main):

```
html,body
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#F8F5EF;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;

}

#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1100px;
}

#content-container
{
    float: left;
    width: 1100px;
    background-image:url('../images/BG1.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 0px;    
}

#content
{
    float: left;
    width: 778px;
    padding: 15px 0px 80px 15px;
    margin: 0 0 60 0px;

}
```

The IE7.css file doesn't modify those items.

Thanks!

G

Comment: Can you post your surrounding CSS/HTML?

Comment: Ok, so there's something else going wrong..Can you post the whole CSS, or replicate the situation somewhere?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've edited my original post to include the html/css.

Comment: If you could post a link to a live page, I could solve this really quickly.

Comment: @thirtydot - I wish everyone would do that, maybe a future SO feature :)

Answer (score 2):

Without posting your surrounding HTML/CSS we can't really help, as this code works in all IE (just tested)

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n3pvP/)

Which leads me to believe you have something affecting the styles.  If you can show that or provide a link, I think more help can be provided.

**Here is the CSS used:**

```
#content {
    width:     100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

**HTML used:**

```
<div id="content">
        content here
    </div>
```

**Updated code, using your css/html provided:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hyVjs/2/

This code is fine.  One of your sub css files is messing you up :)

Have you tried removing your conditional css files and see if it still isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your help -- yep I tried removing the conditional files, still the same... I would post the link to the site but I don't particularly want it to show up in search engines...

Comment: That's cool - it's just hard to troubleshoot the code you've posted, as it works.  It could be something as simple as a missing </div> tag somewhere or something like that.

Comment: @user632097: You could write the site URL inside an image, and post a link to the image. Do it!

Comment: @thirtydot -- then I'd be hosting the image somewhere, which could eventually lead back to.... I'm probably being too cautious. Would a tiny url keep my oh so precious anonymity?

Comment: Put it in a jsfiddle, then update it later (removing the url) - like this one:  http://jsfiddle.net/yGKJj/ then click update

Comment: Good idea! Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/B7RG5/ . I should say that this is mostly NOT my code, I'm modifying an existing site...

Comment: I've looked at your site and it's centered in my IE7 and IE8 - should I be looking for something specific?  Are you testing on a IE-renderer?  Or true IE?

Comment: I'm looking at it on IE7 on a virtual pc. Also the client (who's not using virtual pc) says it's not centered on her IE7. It might depend on the resolution you're using? On my resolution it fills the whole screen, so it *looks* centered, but if I CTRL and roll mouse wheel to reduce the browser display size, the whole site stays on the left (whereas in IE8 it stays in the centre). Does that make sense? Thanks for checking, by the way.

Comment: The only thing I can think is here resolution is like 1280x... And by not centered, she means there is more of a gutter on the right (which is fixed if you change #container { width: 1000px } but other than that you're center on my browsers :)  If anything, it's just off by that 100px.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You could be right there. Perhaps it's time to find out more from the client. Many thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have set the DOCTYPE. If not IE will enable quirk "dirty mode"

Answer (score 1):

text-align is for aligning text...

in ie7 make sure you have given the parent container a width other than auto then all should be well.

Comment: Thanks. I have a width other than auto, see my posted code. I agree about the text-align, I just threw it in out of desperation! In or out it makes no difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this for your container:

```
#container {
   position: absolute;
   margin:0 0 0 50%;
   width:1100px;
   left: -550px; /*half the element width*/
}
```

If the above doesn't fit your needs, try `position:relative;`

I found using percentage margins worked for IE7 when nothing else did. Though auto margins seem to work sometimes - your code in jsFiddle seemed fine under IE7.

The negative positioning to the left is needed to bring back the element, which is centered from its left edge.

Answer (score 0):

If the container is a DIV then

```
#container
{
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:1035px;
}
```

if it does not work, use a css-reset first. It will definitely work.

Comment: Thanks Jogendra, I gave that a go but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
display:block;
```

for the container

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if I'm going to center a container, I usually `text-align:center;` the body and left align inside the container for backwards compatibility. Old habit I'm going to kill some day.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>a box</title>
        <style>
            body { text-align:center; }
            #wrap { width:36em; padding:2em; margin:1em auto; text-align:left; background:#eee; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">&hellip;</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this works, you typically don't want to do global settings, only to change them back.  Using the code that does that specifically, is typically the better approach.  IMO.